# C# WPF add KeyUp event for window with a handler in another page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on a WPF project and I'm new to it. I organize my project like this:

```
MainWindow.xaml         (Contains a NavigationWindow)
  MainWindow.xaml.cs
HomePage.xaml           (Contains a series of function)
  Homepage.xaml.cs
```

The thing is that I want to add a `KeyUp` event to my program, and I want it to call a function in `HomePage.xaml.cs` when a key is pressed. But I found that it is impossible to add a `KeyUp` event to a `Page` object, thus I decided to add it for `NavigationWindow`. However, I cannot reach the function in `HomePage.xaml.cs` inside `NavigationWindow`, so I came up with an idea.

```
var window = Window.GetWindow(this);
((MainWindow) window).KeyUp += new system.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(this.Window_KeyUp);
```

However, this doesn't work and throw a `System.NullReferenceException`. I don't know why it happens. Maybe it wants to say that `this` is `null` in here? But why?

Comment: Use a `UserControl` instead of `Page`. (if possible)

Comment: I suppose that an `UserControl` still cannot be attached with a `KeyUp` event. Also, is that conventional to use `UserControl` instead of `Page` to do navigation and put content in it?

Comment: I am guessing you want to show diff pages in MainWindow. And HomePage is first page, there could be many such pages, and you want to to navigate between them using Arrow Keys ?

Answer (score 0):

Though it is silly, I would like to answer to this question myself. (BTW, I haven't received many answers which upsets me. Luckily I found the problem)

The problem is about `Window.GetWindow(this)`. It returns `null`, which clearly doesn't have a `KeyUp` event. The solution is to change it to `Application.Current.Windows`, which is an array of windows hierarchy. Thus `Application.Current.Windows[0]` can return the `MainWindow` object, which can be attached with the handler.